# ExtJS : line chart : How to get image base64 when the chart finish draw ?

Tags: extjs, base64, linechart

I use ExtJS to create a line chart and create a button to get image base64.Now, I don't want this button. I need an event whitch fire when the line chart finish draw and then get image base64. I found an event "painted", and I try to use it, but it can't work, Why?.

reference：[ExtJS line chart example](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Ext.chart.series.Line.html)

Answer (score 1):

Works just fine for me.
Cartesian Graph with a series and some lines inside that.
Add painted listener to the cartesian graph, call getImage('stream') on the cartesian graph (this), check out the data element of the returned object.

I merely added this listener configuration to the cartesian which will display the png data for the full graph in a MessageBox:

```
   listeners: {
       painted: function(element, eOpts) {
           Ext.Msg.alert('Image Data', this.getImage('stream').data);
       }
   },
```

See below for the adjusted full example from the documentation:

```
Ext.create({
   xtype: 'cartesian',
   renderTo: document.body,
   width: 600,
   height: 400,
   insetPadding: 40,
   listeners: {
       painted: function(element, eOpts) {
           Ext.Msg.alert('Image Data', this.getImage('stream').data);
       }
   },
   store: {
       fields: ['name', 'data1', 'data2'],
       data: [{
           'name': 'metric one',
           'data1': 10,
           'data2': 14
       }, {
           'name': 'metric two',
           'data1': 7,
           'data2': 16
       }, {
           'name': 'metric three',
           'data1': 5,
           'data2': 14
       }, {
           'name': 'metric four',
           'data1': 2,
           'data2': 6
       }, {
           'name': 'metric five',
           'data1': 27,
           'data2': 36
       }]
   },
   axes: [{
       type: 'numeric',
       position: 'left',
       fields: ['data1'],
       title: {
           text: 'Sample Values',
           fontSize: 15
       },
       grid: true,
       minimum: 0
   }, {
       type: 'category',
       position: 'bottom',
       fields: ['name'],
       title: {
           text: 'Sample Values',
           fontSize: 15
       }
   }],
   series: [{
       type: 'line',
       style: {
           stroke: '#30BDA7',
           lineWidth: 2
       },
       xField: 'name',
       yField: 'data1',
       marker: {
           type: 'path',
           path: ['M', - 4, 0, 0, 4, 4, 0, 0, - 4, 'Z'],
           stroke: '#30BDA7',
           lineWidth: 2,
           fill: 'white'
       }
   }, {
       type: 'line',
       fill: true,
       style: {
           fill: '#96D4C6',
           fillOpacity: .6,
           stroke: '#0A3F50',
           strokeOpacity: .6,
       },
       xField: 'name',
       yField: 'data2',
       marker: {
           type: 'circle',
           radius: 4,
           lineWidth: 2,
           fill: 'white'
       }
   }]
});
```